# ssh RPi from PC - How to share internet connection?

Tags: ssh, networking, raspberry-pi, ethernet, wlan

I have Raspberry Pi connected with PC on eth0 port. I am using eth0 to ssh RPi. I have web application on RPi that requires Internet access.

Now, I set static ip to RPi (192.168.1.50) and to PC (192.168.1.66).
I can connect to Internet through wireless adapter on PC and also through USB Wi-Pi adapter on RPi.

Here is PC's `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:a8:2a:7e:fd:7d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.66  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ea8:2aff:fe7e:fd7d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20422 (20.4 KB)  TX bytes:80928 (80.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:460006 (460.0 KB)  TX bytes:460006 (460.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:ad:08:67:5e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::36e6:adff:fe08:675e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10338 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6496258 (6.4 MB)  TX bytes:1391363 (1.3 MB)
```

When I connect to Internet on RPi, wlan0 gets `192.168.1.10`.

The problem is, when I ssh through PC to RPi, I don't have Internet access on RPi and `route -n` shows eth0 as prefered interface.

I am trying to bridge wireless and ethernet connection, either on PC and to share Internet to RPi while doing ssh, or to bridge connections on RPi, so I could have wlan0 and eth0 active at the same time.

I tried to `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, and also used `MASQUERADE` option on `iptables`, but with no success. I am missing something, and doing something wrong but can't actually see it.

Can you explain to me how can I achieve my goal here, how to set up `/etc/network/interfaces` file and anything else that I should consider?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**With commands:** https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections (Wireless in mid)

**Install bridge-utils:**

```
apt-get install bridge-utils (ubuntu)

aptitude install bridge-utils (debain)

nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add below lines

```
pre-up iwconfig wlan0 essid $YOUR_ESSID (wifi name)

bridge_hw $MAC_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_WIRELESS_CARD(34:e6:ad:08:67:5e)
```

**Install ebtables:**

```
aptitude install ebtables (debian)

apt-get install ebtables (ubuntu)
```

setup bridge network with wlan0 MAC address($MAC=34:e6:ad:08:67:5e)

```
ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j snat --to-src $MAC --snat-arp --snat-target ACCEPT
```

Add device MAC address which need internet access:(replace $ip with ip, $MAC with MAC address of pi and computer)

**Set rules :**

```
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p IPv4 -i wlan0 --ip-dst $IP -j dnat --to-dst $MAC --dnat-target ACCEPT
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p ARP -i wlan0 --arp-ip-dst $IP -j dnat --to-dst $MAC --dnat-target ACCEPT
```

Repeat the above command for adding both pi and computer.

**Save rules:**

```
EBTABLES_ATOMIC_FILE=/root/ebtables-atomic ebtables -t nat --atomic-save

EBTABLES_ATOMIC_FILE=/root/ebtables-atomic ebtables -t nat --atomic-commit
```

**With GUI:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/126276)

Comment: @jasonwryan answer updated with command.